# How to search for 2 or more matches in a single string?

Tags: php, string-comparison, string-matching

I want to search for two or more words, but not able to match the exact word.

If I use some other function like `stripos()` I don't get the required output.

```
$string = "abc india ltd";
$Arr = array('xyz ab','abc india', 'pqr', 'yz lmn');
$Arr = implode('',$Arr);
if (preg_match_all("/$string/", $Arr)) {   
     echo '<b>'.'found'.'<font color="green">'.$string.'</font>'.'</b>';          
}
```

or (Both Same, But want to avoid using inside a loop)

```
$string = "abc india ltd";
$Arr = array('xyz ab','abc india', 'pqr', 'yz lmn');   
foreach ($Arr as $value) {
    if (preg_match_all("/$string/", $value)) {   
        echo '<b>'.'found '.'<font color="green">'.$string.'</font>'.'</b>';          
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please try to elaborate what you want actually. what is your desired outcome you want based on this input data. Please be more clear otherwise no-one can answer.

Comment: if two exact words are their in the array ..i should get the output found. but not one word matches eg xyz india should not match

Comment: Yabes Nadar Please check my answer below and test it with all your possible cases and if it worked for all cases then mark+up-vote it as an accepted answer.Thanks

Comment: You misplaced the arguments to `preg_match_all` function. The first one is the regex (and you put `$string` into the pattern), then comes the input (and you have `$value`), the third one is the resulting array var. There may be more, but these are most important. If you have `$string = "abc,india ltd";` the accepted solution won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want like this:-

```
<?php

$string = "abc india";

$Arr = array('xyz india','abc india', 'pqr', 'yz lmn',"xyz abc india");

foreach($Arr as $val){
 $explode_string = explode(" ",$string);
 $counter =0;
 foreach($explode_string as $explode_str){
     if(strpos($val,$explode_str) !== FALSE){
        $counter +=1;
     }
 }
 if($counter>=2){
   echo $val. " have exact ".$counter. " word matches";
   echo PHP_EOL;
 }
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/831808

Note:- check it with all possible test-cases and let us know, worked or not?

Answer (score 0):

This leverages some smart array functions to keep the code block concise and avoid manually incrementing a counter:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2e24952eaad0d8df033757d664a4e9cba29a041d))

```
$input_string="abc india ltd";
$input_array=explode(' ',$input_string);
$search_array=array('xyz ab','abc india','ltd abc','yz lmn');
foreach($search_array as $search_string){
    if(sizeof(array_intersect($input_array,explode(' ',$search_string)))>1){  
        echo "More than one word in $search_string was found in $input_string\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
More than one word in abc india was found in abc india ltd
More than one word in ltd abc was found in abc india ltd
```

*note, `array_intersect()` generates a new array that only contains elements that exist in both provided arrays. `sizeof()` is an alias of `count()`.